# Powershell To Export To CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have my method which (unless I did something stupid) worked perfectly yesterday for exporting to csv.  However, today I keep getting this erro:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized"
>
> - $rowCount=$SqlAdapter.Fill($dt)
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

And this is my syntax:

```
$server = "serverinstance"
$database = "databaseinstance"
$savefile = "C:\Test\sqlresults.csv"
$SelectQuery = "Select Top 1 * from madeuptable"
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$cmd=$connection.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $SelectQuery 

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$rowCount=$SqlAdapter.Fill($dt)

if ($rowCount -gt 0) { $dt| Export-Csv $savefile -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation }
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: `$SelectQuery` seems to be missing from the script..

Comment: @Kenney - copy/paste error updated.

Comment: What if you run the posted code snippet, does that work?

Comment: @Kenney - no the posted code snippet produces the error.

Comment: I can run your code no problem. Your copy/paste error would explain the error message you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the SqlDataAdaper using the query and the connection instead (and drop the cmd).

Example:

```
$SqlAdapter = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter ($SelectQuery, $connection)
```

Comment: I commented out my two lines that begin with $cmd and added in yoursw and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your $server and $database variables. I just ran your script against my own SQL server and it worked just fine for me.

**EDIT**:

Here is what I ran:

```
$server = "FAR-L2484\HOLDER_SQL"  ## Hostname\InstanceID
$database = "MASTER"
$savefile = "C:\Test\sqlresults.csv"
$SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables"
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$cmd=$connection.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $SelectQuery 

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$rowCount=$SqlAdapter.Fill($dt)

$dt| Export-Csv $savefile -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
$connection.Close()
```

and this is what I got in C:\test\sqlresults.csv

```
"TABLE_CATALOG","TABLE_SCHEMA","TABLE_NAME","TABLE_TYPE"
"master","dbo","spt_fallback_db","BASE TABLE"
"master","dbo","spt_fallback_dev","BASE TABLE"
"master","dbo","spt_fallback_usg","BASE TABLE"
"master","dbo","spt_values","VIEW"
"master","dbo","spt_monitor","BASE TABLE"
"master","dbo","MSreplication_options","BASE TABLE"
```